# OS X - WLAN and LAN simultaneously on 2 ISP?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, isp

On iMac I want to use 2 different applications and using 2 different ISP. Is that possible and if how config?

- Weather app: Connected to my WLAN using ISP 1
- Camera app: Connected to my LAN (Ethernet) using ISP 2

How do ‘bind’ applications to their ports (LAN / WLAN)?

(OS X: Lion)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot bind applications to network paths. What you can do is to configure different gateways for different destinations. But this is a lot of work:

- You need to find out which internet server each application uses.
- You need to find out the default gateway to use for each ISP.
- Then you have to configure the routing table so that all destinations for Weather App will be routed to ISP1, and all destinations for Camera app routed to ISP2.